# Back button on application not appearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

My back button is not appearing on my navigation controller when running the application on the simulator. it was previously appearing but not anymore for some reason.

Comment: That's unfortunate to hear but are you going to include anything that might help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad()`, add `self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false`
if you still don't get help from this, kindly add some code or give some extra details.

Answer (score -1):

```
Navigate the viewController instead of present.
```